# Error in Galaxy tab a: 'Unable to restart your device. Verification failed' after supersu

Tags: samsung, root-access, samsung-galaxy-tab, superuser, samsung-knox

I own a Galaxy tab a 10.1 with s pen (2016). I flashed via odin, twrp 3.1.1.0 and the system booted fine. Then I flashed the last version of SuperSU and since then the system doesn't turn on and I get the famous
`Verification failed. Unable to restart your device. The integrity verification has failed. You need to restart your device to factory default settings. This will erase your data.`

As I can't access my data in twrp, I tried to flash no-verity-opt-encrypt (6.0) but it doesn't help and I still can't access my data on the internal storage from twrp. Before I do a factory reset, I'd like to backup my data. Do you know if it's possible or how can I fix this error?

Will flashing the stock firmware help?

Answer (score 0):

Uhh, ok. If you're able to boot to TWRP, click mount and put a check mark in each box. Go back to TWRP file manager and poooof you shout see what you're looking for. Backup all partitions, then do a factory wipe.  Go to restore and only check "data". I suggest you root with Magisk (system-less) and find yourself a sweet custom ROM like AEX.

Comment: Thanks but I can't mount data. I have omb in my internal storage under twrp.

Answer (score 0):

Do a backup of whatever you have left of your ROM. Move to computer. Use Odin and flash stock ROM, then flash the AOF8 non Knox kernel from XDA. Flash Magisk 17.1 or lower. Boot. Check to make sure you have the proper TWRP for your device! Go to Lineage or AOSP and find your ROM for your device. Flash it. Flash Magisk 17.3.

Comment: so my data is lost ? Do you have any idea how to save it without wiping the data partition?

Comment: by the way I couldn't find AOF8 non-knox kernel for this device in xda. can you please send a link?

Comment: If you didn't erace data partition, it's still there somewhere, but the path is corrupt. Make sure you install BusyBox, you can find a flashable static BusyBox on XDA. But like I said, flash just your system partition first which may restore the path to your data, but you might loose root which is probably a good thing. Magisk my friend.